# how to select only positive numbers from already grouped set of data?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

here is my code, I have an excel sheet with columns named a,b,c,d and I have grouped the data as shown in below code but the issue is data was partitioned into multiple groups and I want the sum of only positive numbers from column 'C' only. please explain me using my code instead of giving other code examples. thanks.

```
result=((df.groupby(['a','b'])['c']).sum())/(df.groupby(['a','b'])['d'].sum())
print(result)
```

Comment: You can use boolean masking to filter out values of c that are only positive before you group `df[df['c']>=0].groupby...`

Comment: please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)